# Is there any method to locate a line with line num in a text file with java api?

Tags: java, file, numbers, line, locate

I hope there do have an operation for this topic,'cause I don't want to loop the file once again,and hope to read the file from the specific location say a line number,and then I will read the file with much more threads than just one.

Any idea?
Thanks first!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge there isn't anything like this in the standard Java API. You could use [LineIterator](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/LineIterator.html) or (even just a basic [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)) to build a custom class that does what you need, [like this guy did](http://mark.koli.ch/2010/01/java-jumptoline-jump-to-a-line-in-a-file.html).

Note that a [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) sounds promising but unfortunately for you, the `seek()` method takes an offset in bytes and not in lines so unless your lines are all always the same length, this wont' work for you.

Comment: Sorry for not standing by.and because the file is so big that I just do read each line and have the line number as the message.and the goal for this is to split the file with more threads for special line number at the same time.Using the method of readLine() is to slow to me.Thanks for your reply...